# Kestrel in .Net 6 console App - NullReferenceException when calling HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()

Tags: .net, console, nullreferenceexception, kestrel

I'm writing a windows server with .Net 6 and I need to listen for internal network http requests.
I decided to use Kestrel.
Everything works find when I send a http request, the request is accepted by Kestrel and I can manage it my code.
But when I want to send an answer via `HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync()`, then a NullReferenceException is launched.
The stack trace is the following:

> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.CreateResponseHeader(Boolean
> appCompleted)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.InitializeResponseAsync(Int32
> firstWriteByteCount)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1
> data, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpResponseStream.WriteAsync(Byte[]
> buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse
> response, String text, Encoding encoding, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpResponseWritingExtensions.WriteAsync(HttpResponse
> response, String text, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

My code is quite simple.
First the services are registered:

```
IPAddress address = settings.BindAddress == null ? IPAddress.Any : IPAddress.Parse(settings.BindAddress);

services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Listen(address, settings.ListeningPort);
});

services.AddSingleton<IServer, KestrelServer>();
services.AddSingleton<ITransportFactory, SocketTransportFactory>();
services.AddSingleton<IApplicationLifetime, ApplicationLifetime>();
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextFactory, HttpContextFactory>();
```

Then the server is started in a class that implements IHttpApplication and can manage the requests :

```
public class HttpController : IHttpApplication<HttpContext>
{
    private readonly IServer _server;
    private readonly ILogger<HttpController> _logger;
    
    public HttpController(IServer server, IHttpContextFactory httpContextFactory, ILogger<HttpController> logger)
    {
        _server = server;
        _httpContextFactory = httpContextFactory;
        _logger = logger;            
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        _server.StartAsync(this, cancellationToken);
    }

    public HttpContext CreateContext(IFeatureCollection contextFeatures)
    {
        return _httpContextFactory.Create(contextFeatures);
    }

    public void DisposeContext(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        _httpContextFactory.Dispose(context);
    }

    public async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{Method} Http request received: {Path}", context.Request.Method, context.Request.Path);
        
        try
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/hello"))
            {
                var resp = "Hello World!";
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(resp);                    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError("Error while managing HTTP {Method} request to {Path} : {message}", context.Request.Method, context.Request.Path, ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea why `context.Response.WriteAsync()` is launching this NullReferenceException?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after 2 days of investigation, I've found a work-around.
I had to use package Microsoft.AspNetCore.App.
And then I had to add the services like this :

```
services.AddSingleton<IServer, KestrelServer>();
services.AddSingleton<IConnectionListenerFactory, SocketTransportFactory>();                        
services.AddTransient<IHttpContextFactory, DefaultHttpContextFactory>();
```

It means that I had to remove the `ApplicationLifeTime` line. It is managed by the package added.
And I had to replace `ITransportFactory` by `IConnectionListenerFactory`, and the same for `HttpContextFactory` that I replaced by `DefaultHttpContextFactory`...

Part of the answer has been found here :
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28112